# R - binding variables based on names in list

Tags: r

I want to be able to construct a vector of strings where the elements are listed in another vector.

So I have,

```
 fruits <- c("strawberries", "plums", "cherries")
```

and I want to be able to create a vector that combines the character values from variables I have with the names `strawberries`, `plums`, and `cherries`. They look like;

```
 strawberries <- c("straw_size", "straw_colour")
 plums <- c("plum_size", "plum_taste")
 cherries <- c("cherry_size", "cherry_amt")
```

What I want to see is this, which is in the order of the original `fruits` ordering.

```
 fruits_total <- c("straw_size", "straw_colour", "plum_size", 
          "plum_taste", "cherry_size", "cherry_amt")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need `mget`

```
 unlist(mget(fruits), use.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks mate! Didn't know the `mget` function.